# Parse XML from File with Attributes (php)

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I need to parse an XML file using PHP.

I have found tutorials that show how to load the file and also how to parse it with attributes, but no one puts the two together.

I understand that to load the file, I write:
$xml = simplexml_load_file('filename.xml');

The format of the xml file is such that the information I want is within tags.
ex:

```
<match date="April 19, 2011" timezone="EST" status="Final" time="8:00 PM" formatted_date="19.04.2011" id="7342">
```

Let's say I want the date.

When I read about parsing xml with PHP I would expect to write:

```
$date =  match->attributes()->date;
```

but this just returns an empty result. I can't figure out how to link it with the file. In other words - how do I link the above line of code with $xml to get the content I want out of the file?

Thanks in advance,
John

Comment: You didn't post the XML file.

Comment: You need to refine this question to make more sense. What does the document look like, and what are you trying to get?

Comment: Where did `$match` come from?

Comment: Please post full examples. Use 4 spaces before any line of code for syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

I swear to God, if you do REGEX PARSING to try to pull out attribute values of a structured document YOAR DOING IT WRONG!

Rather than "parsing", you probably want to use the [DOMNode API](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php) to traverse the document using a query (written in [XPATH](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/)) to find what you're looking for.